# How to access the data of a table from parent database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `UserTable` in dbo database inside a `Company` database..

I know if I am writing a query in the `Company` database I need to access the `UserTable` by `[dbo].[UserTable]` but now I am in the dbo database such that I can access the `UserTable` directly..  but now I have a table named `UserNameTable` in the `Company` database.

Is there a way to access the `UserNameTable` without using 'use CompanyDatabase' like `[parent].UserNameTable]...`  it would just be more convenient..

Tell me if I need to make it clearer..

Thank you in advance...

Comment: create connection with another database and use connection reference.

Comment: yeah..  that will definitely work..  but is it not possible simply by using aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, the answer is

Simply use aliases such as [dbo].[parent].[table] as 'mytab', or if you are fetching the same data from same multiple tables often, try to create a view, such as create view as (sql select query). The view acts as a logical table.

For example try like this,

```
select
    LocalTable.*, tmp.*
from
    LocalTable,
    [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable] as 'tmp'
```

This should definitely work.

Comment: Thanks man..  this works.. sadly there is no short way or alias in sql for accessing the parent db..  seems like the only way is to access using the whole path including the server name..  thanks again..  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the database directly from query syntax by using `[databasename].[schema].[TableName]`

You do not have to use

```
Use MyDatabase
Go
```

You can use

```
select * from MyDatabase.dbo.MyUserTable
```

Comment: yea thats the problem.. i tried this.. it should have worked..  but it didnt.. i also tried [master].[dbo].[UserNameTable]